# Check if user entered a digit

Tags: ruby, regex, user-input

I am working on a small game where maths questions are displayed and user inputs answers.

When the user writes a letter , its converted to 0 , but I would like the program to ask the user to re-enter the Input .

The code should accept + , - , and digits 
Every other input should trigger the loop to run until correct input is entered.

Heres how my code looks ....

```
def ask_questions

  question = @questionAndAnswerList[@currQuestion]

  a = question.question.q1
  b = question.question.q2

  print("what is #{a} #{a+b > question.answer ? "-" : '+'} #{b} ? = ")
  puts @userAnswer = gets().chomp

  #test if @userAnswer has a Digit value

  while /[+|-]\D/ =~ @userAnswer
    puts "Found a non digit in your input , please try again...."
    puts @userAnswer = gets.chomp

  end

  @userAnswer = @userAnswer.to_i

end
```

Comment: `while /[+|-]\D/ =~ @userAnswer` this may be change to `while /[+|-]?\D+/ =~ @userAnswer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Integer()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer), which throws an exception if there is no conversion.

```
begin
  @userAnswer = Integer(@userAnswer, 10)
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "#{@userAnswer.inspect} is not an integer, please try again..."
  @userAnswer = gets.chomp
  retry
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@userAnswer.scan(/[^0-9]/)
```

This will check if the user answered anything that's not a digit in the range of 0 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Enumerable#all?** to check whether all of the characters are digits. This will check if every character is in the range 0-9. If there's a non-digit it will ask to repeat the code.

```
while !@userAnswer.chars.all?{|c|[*'0'..'9'].include?(c)}
  puts "Found a non digit in your input , please try again...."
  puts @userAnswer = gets.chomp
end
```